# Select the biggest cycle in a graph given constraints on edges

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, discrete-optimization

I have a graph fully connected whose vertices represents points in a city. On each edge I also have information on the distance between two points and an estimation of the time needed to go from a point to another.
Now I'm wondering if there's an efficient way to get the biggest cycle given a starting point and a time limit. In other words, given a max time limit, I want to maximize the number of points in a cycle.

The only solution I found is something like a "brute force" algorithm which try each node until find a suitable solution, but it's horribly slow.

Comment: Maybe you can modify the algorithms for TSP (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem)...
I think that you have an instance of an knapsack problem, maybe that helps aswell (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem)

Comment: This is a special case (with equal node weights) of the *orienteering problem*, also known as *profit-collecting TSP*.

Comment: Can you please share your data?

Comment: @RobPratt many thanks for your suggestions, indeed that's exactly what I'm looking for! I'm not a metematican so sorry if I'm not formal in the definition of the problem. Basically the graph is composed by vertices which represent locations on a map, each vertex is connected to each other and on each edge there's the information on the time (estimated ) or distance between two points

Comment: Vertices are not so much, usually we're talking about 50-100 vertices

Comment: I meant: Can you please explicitly share the locations, time estimates, and time limit?